# How to aggregate rows on a pair of columns, while handling other columns in specific ways?

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, data-analysis

I've been playing around with aggregation functions in R, but haven't really managed to solve my problem.

The issue is as follows, my data looks something like this (note that there are several more columns but they are irrelevant for the sake of the example):

```
Description Delta   E.Mass  Charge  RT
TFGTFSVEEYVLPK  0.0111  1615.82 2   94.5554
VSGVGNNISFEEK   0.0073  1378.68 2   51.902
DGNGNTWLTAFVTK  0.0088  1522.75 2   96.1395
DGNGNTWLTAFVTK  0.9961  1523.74 2   98.289
DGNGNTWLTAFVTK  0.9979  1523.74 2   99.1948
DGNGNTWLTAFVTK  0.9958  1523.74 2   98.333
DGNGNTWLTAFVTK  0.9987  1523.74 2   99.2278
DGNGNTWLTAFVTK  0.0084  1522.75 2   95.4033
DVDDPMVSQGLR 15.99492@M6 delta:13.700001    1.013   1347.63 2   46.353
GFGLSPTVGLTAFKPF    0.0052  1637.89 2   109.398
GFGLSPTVGLTAFKPF    0.0092  1637.89 2   108.368
GFGLSPTVGLTAFKPF    0.0089  1637.89 2   108.339
ILDSNEPCGGQK    0.0086  1316.61 2   31.9053
LAPDPSLVIYAIFPSGGVVADK  -0.006  2228.2  3   118.385
LAPDPSLVIYAIFPSGGVVADK  -0.0034 2228.21 3   118.413
LAPDPSLVIYAIFPSGGVVADK  -0.0082 2228.2  3   117.739
PSYQEEAVTK  0.005   1150.56 2   32.2676
PSYQEEAVTK  0.005   1150.56 2   32.2676
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

1. aggregate on `Description`
2. pick the smallest `Delta`.
3. Average the `RT` values as `RT_mean`
4. Add columns `RT_mean - N`, `RT_mean + N` for an arbitrary number N.
5. Leave all other columns untouched/ignored in the output.

I have looked at aggregate function but it appears that I cannot do column specific voodoo using that function.

I tried `by` (in combination with `rbind`) and `ddply` but no real breakthrough. I'm sure it's possible to do what I want to do, just a matter of getting the arguments to these functions right. But since I'm on a really tight schedule I can't really do my regular trial and error learning process.

Any help or guidance is really appreciated, especially with some comments explaining the answer, in case I need to modify the provided answers to fit the data.

**EDIT:** In the light of the comments here's a simplified example, with the below input:

```
ID    Delta    Emass    Ch    RT
A    0.0084    1522.75    2    95.4033
A    0.0088    1522.75    2    96.1395
A    0.9961    1523.74    2    98.2890
B    1.0130    1347.63    2    46.3530
C   -0.0060    2228.20    3   118.3850
C   -0.0034    2228.21    3   118.4130
C    0.0082    2228.20    3   117.7390
D    0.0050    1150.56    2    32.2676
D    0.0050    1150.56    2    32.2676
```

desired output would be:

```
ID    Delta    Emass    Ch    RT_mean    RT1    RT2
A    0.0084    1522.75    2    96.6106    93.6106    99.6106
B    1.0130    1347.63    2    46.3530    43.3530    49.3530
C   -0.0060    2228.20    3   118.1790   115.1790   121.1790
D    0.0050    1150.56    2    32.2676    29.2676    35.2676
```

Comment: Please explain: `calculate E.Mass - Delta, alternatively pick the (Delta, E.Mass) pair with the smallest Delta.`. I don't understand the second part. Moreover, for E.Mass - Delta, you want the difference of the two means?

Comment: `group_by` and `mutate` from `dplyr` package will be a start.

Comment: Please provide your desired output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg a simpler example and desired output is now provided

Answer (score 1):

These kind of manipulations are very easy using `dplyr` package try this.
couldn't understand smallest delta part. Otherwise this code will do everything else. An easier reproducible example with expected answer at the end would have helped.

```
 library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Description) %>% summarize(dif = E.Mass - Delta,
RT_mean = mean(RT),RT_x = RT_mean - 2, RT_y RT_mean -3)
```